# Integration test with native SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, integration-testing

I have some trouble with integration test. I'm using python 3.5, SQLAlchemy 1.2.0b3, latest docker image of postgresql. So, I wrote test:

```
# tests/integration/usecases/test_users_usecase.py

class TestGetUsersUsecase(unittest.TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    Base.metadata.reflect(_pg)
    Base.metadata.drop_all(_pg)
    Base.metadata.create_all(_pg)

    self._session = sessionmaker(bind=_pg, autoflush=True, autocommit=False, expire_on_commit=True)
    self.session = self._session()

    self.session.add(User(id=1, username='user1'))
    self.session.commit()

    self.pg = PostgresService(session=self.session)

def test_get_user(self):
    expected = User(id=1, username='user1')
    boilerplates.get_user_usecase(storage_service=self.pg, id=1, expected=expected)

# tests/boilerplates/usecases/user_usecases.py

def get_user_usecase(storage_service, id, expected):
    u = GetUser(storage_service=storage_service)
    actual = u.apply(id=id)

    assert expected == actual
```

In usecase I did next:

```
# usecases/users.py

class GetUser(object):
"""
Usecase for getting user from storage service by Id
"""

def __init__(self, storage_service):
    self.storage_service = storage_service

def apply(self, id):
    user = self.storage_service.get_user_by_id(id=id)
    if user is None:
        raise UserDoesNotExists('User with id=\'%s\' does not exists' % id)
    return user
```

storage_service.get_user_by_id looks like:

```
# infrastructure/postgres.py (method of Postgres class)

def get_user_by_id(self, id):
    from anna.domain.user import User

    return self.session.query(User).filter(User.id == id).one_or_none()
```

And it does not work in my integration test. But if I add print(actual) in test before assert - all is OK. I thought that my test is bad, I try many variants and all does not works. Also I tried return generator from storage_service.get_user_by_id() and it also does not work. What I did wrong? It works good only if print() was called in test.